# Why are multiple rows ('versions') saved with eloquent, when I only edit one

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I use a versioning system to save multiple versions of a 'minor' (a model in my application). It contains quite a few fields, like name, goals, requirements, subject and many more. When I save a new version, or 'version 2', using eloquent, it also changes the other version.

I have tried multiple ways of saving the minor, like requesting the first one and updating it like below, or changing each individual item one-by-one.

```
Minor::limit(1)
            ->where("id", $id)
            ->where('version', $_POST['version'])
            ->first()
            ->update([
                'name' => $_POST['name'],
                'ects' => floatval($_POST['ects']),
                'contact_hours' => intval($_POST['contact_hours']),
                'education_type' => $_POST['education_type'],
                'language' => $_POST['language'],
                'subject' => Input::get('subject'),
                'goals' => Input::get('goals'),
                'requirements' => Input::get('requirements'),
            ]);
```

It should only save the selected version, but instead, it overwrites all versions of the minor with the same ID and saves them to the database.
How can I prevent this, or does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: dump $_POST['version'] and see what is in that

Comment: The version is correct, it's the selected version (so 1, 2, 3, etc...). It also selects the correct minor. But when it saves, it overwrites all the minors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this happened or how to fix it using the same method. I have however found a way around it. I now update and save the minor with the ->update([...]) method build into eloquent.

```
        Minor::where([["id", "139858"], ["version", Input::get('version')]])
            ->update([
                'name' => Input::get('name'),
                'ects' => Input::get('ects'),
                'contact_hours' => Input::get('contact_hours'),
                'education_type' => Input::get('education_type'),
                'language' => Input::get('language'),
                'subject' => Input::get('subject'),
                'requirements' => Input::get('requirements'),
                'goals' => Input::get('goals')
            ]);
```

This doesn't seem to alter the other versions. This is the only way I found to make it work, you can't make a variable of the object, change values and then save it. That would overwrite the other versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `updateOrCreate` method:

```php
Minor::updateOrCreate([
           'id' => $id,
           'version' => $_POST['version']
       ],[
           'name' => $_POST['name'],
           'ects' => floatval($_POST['ects']),
           'contact_hours' => intval($_POST['contact_hours']),
           'education_type' => $_POST['education_type'],
           'language' => $_POST['language'],
           'subject' => Input::get('subject'),
           'goals' => Input::get('goals'),
           'requirements' => Input::get('requirements'),
        ]);
```

Comment: This stil overwrites all versions of the minor. Thanks though, didn’t know this is a function.

Comment: Are you sure the versions are correctly stored in you DB?

Comment: Yeah, I checked just checked it (again, to be sure ). I have a primary key over the id and version, so no minor can have multiple of the same versions.